# Multiple path in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying nginx for the first time and I am running it locally. I have been able to get my services up but I have a puzzling question because I run a Microservice and during upgrade I want to be able to just block a particular service.

Now, each service has a a path eg

`\api\v1\wallet`
`\api\v1\card`

the issue I have is that both wallet and card path are in the same service.

If I have different paths would I have to duplicate or there's a way I could make it work better?

Here is my conf file

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {

    server {

        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;

        location ~ ^/api/v1/user {
            rewrite ^/api/v1/user/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://user-service:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api/v1/wallet/ {
            # rewrite /api/v1/wallet/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/wallet/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api/v1/card/ {
            # rewrite /api/v1/wallet/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/card/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should integrate them as follows:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {

    server {

        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;

        location ~ ^/api/v1/user {
            rewrite ^/api/v1/user/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://user-service:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ^~ /api/v1/(wallet|card)/$ {
            # rewrite /api/v1/wallet/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error `nginx-proxy_1            | 2022/03/06 12:28:40 [error] 31#31: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/api/v1/wallet/health" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/v1/wallet/health HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
nginx-proxy_1            | 172.20.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:12:28:40 +0000] "GET /api/v1/wallet/health HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.1 Safari/605.1.15"`

Comment: @King it seems another error and not related to your question